# Quem é "o homem da fava rica"?

Tags: português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas

De vez em quando, a minha avó mencionava "o homem da fava rica". Infelizmente, na altura não achei importante perguntar o que tal significa, e, agora, ja é tarde para perguntar.  Qual é a origem desta expressão? E o que significa?

Comment: Por este [link](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ate-vir-a-mulher-da-fava-rica/20343), parece que significa um homem querido.

Comment: @Schilive Obrigado.  O link tem material suficiente para uma resposta